# Need help to fix Javascript Accordion minimize and maximize issue (check attached JsFiddle and steps)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### **Need help to fix Javascript Accordion minimize and maximize issue**

### Steps to reproduce:

- #### A. Happy path works fine:

  1. Click + for Accordion.
  2. Click Yes radio and the div expands showing buttons.
- #### B. Different path fails (need help to fix this part)

  1. Click + for Accordion.
  2. Click No radio and the div expands not showing buttons (works).
  3. Click - now for Accordion.
  4. Click + again for Accordion.
  5. Click Yes radio now and this fails to expand full (**fix/help needed here).

### [Problematic JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvchaitanya/tjb7tcqk/9/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #b2b2b2;
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

h1 {
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).on("click",'[name=jenkinsgroup1]',function(e){
  $('.toHide').hide();
  $("#jenkinsgroup-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
  $("#jenkinsgroup").css('background','#e5e5e5');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div class='col' id='jenkinsgroup'>
              <br>&emsp;Jenkins Integration?              
                <input type="radio" name="jenkinsgroup1" value="1">
        Yes       
                <input type="radio" name="jenkinsgroup1" value="2">
                No            
              <div id="jenkinsgroup-1" class="toHide" style="display:none color:black">   
                      <br>&emsp;ServerUrl&nbsp;&nbsp;                   
                            <input id="server" type="text" placeholder="Text input">        
                      <br><br>&emsp;JobName&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input id="jobname" type="text" placeholder="Text input" style="margin-bottom:10px">
            
        </div>
              <div id="jenkinsgroup-2" class="toHide" style="display:none color:black">             
              </div>              
          </div>
</div>
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
                  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            var ele = document.getElementsByName("jenkinsgroup1");
             for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
                ele[i].checked = false;
                    $("#jenkinsgroup").css('background','#ffffff');
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            $('.toHide').hide();
        }
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that "max-height" on the parent div `<div class="panel">` does not change from in your **B** path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this https://jsfiddle.net/tjb7tcqk/13/

your click listener has been updated, removed clearing the max-height, added a toggle for `#jenkinsgroup` and `$('.toHide').hide();` has been placed outside the if condition

```
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {debugger
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
            var ele = document.getElementsByName("jenkinsgroup1");
             for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
                ele[i].checked = false;
                    $("#jenkinsgroup").css('background','#ffffff').toggle()
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            $("#jenkinsgroup").show()
        }
        $('.toHide').hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, your solution works like charm!!!!...I have accepted as answer...Can you help me know what was the issue with my code and the root cause behind why it failed?

Answer (score 0):

[This updated JS-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjb7tcqk/11/) solves your problem. Its a very static approach though, since im passing a fixed height of `"128px"`.

```
$(document).on("click",'[name=jenkinsgroup1]',function(e){
  $('.toHide').hide();
  $("#jenkinsgroup-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
  $("#jenkinsgroup").css('background','#e5e5e5');

  // new code-block
  if (this.value == 1) {
    $("div.panel").css("maxHeight", "128px");
  }
});
```

As you can see (above) I've inserted a if-clause that fixes the max-height problem for your **B-path**.

I hope this helps you getting into the right direction to solve the problem.

On a side-note:
 *I (myself) consider it bad practice to use jQuery and native-JS syantax together. You should stick to either jQuery or native-Js.*